# How to remove “The Wi-Fi network does not appear to be connected to the internet” prompt on iOS 13+

Tags: ios, react-native, iot

I'm working on an IoT device that does not have an internet connection available. When I use the iPad App to connect with my IoT device through Wi-Fi, Apple show "The Wi-Fi network does not appear to be connected to the internet". Is there a way to remove this prompt? or is there any setting in XCode I can do to tell my App this is an IoT device and does not connect to the real internet?

Comment: I've seen that prompt before and I'm pretty sure it's an os feature and not app dependent, if you have control of the wifi network you're connecting to there might be some hack you can do network side that would trick the os into not displaying the alert? Just a thought.